# Create Private Repo creates public repository Visual Studio 2015 Git extension

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to avoid public repository being created when checked the "Create Private Repo" checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [issue 62](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/62#issuecomment-136589545) and [PR64](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/pull/64)

If you upgrade to [v1.0.14](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/releases/tag/v1.0.14) of the [GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio), that will prevent that public repo to be created.

> We've deployed a change to the GitHub.com API that prevents new public repositories from being created by versions of the Visual Studio extension prior to 1.0.14.
>
> **Old versions of the extension will show an error message** requesting users to update their extension along with an explanation on how to do so.

The message will be:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/310137/9597988/5e365886-5087-11e5-99b4-2c248fd2f811.png]

See [this comment for the upgrade process](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/62#issuecomment-136802869).